# echo content within a div tag on the same interface

Tags: php

I have a scenario like this: Simply a *.php page with a PHP content on top followed with a HTML content. Now with an application of `PHP_SELF`, I need to echo the message within HTML without loosing HTML interface once the message is echoed within the 'div1' tag. Is this possible?

I tried replacing echo with `$msg['div1'] = 'Some message'` and inside `div1` tag `<?= $msgxx['display_log'] ?>` but doesn't seems to be a valid code. Please share your views. Code below just to explain my approach. Thanks.

```
<?php

echo 'some message';
?>

<html>
 <form .....>
 <div>
   <div id="div1"></div>
   <div><input type="submit" id="submit1"></div>
 </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In php you `$message='<b>Hello, world!</b>'`. In html

```
   <div id="div1"><?php echo $message ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include inline PHP in your html, perhaps that is where the confusion is coming from? It doesn't always have to be at the top of the page. just wrap your PHP with the `<?php ... ?>` tags.

In your case, if you wanted to echo `some message` inside of `div1`:

```
 <div id="div1"><?php echo 'some message'; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to echo PHP data within HTML? If that is the case, keep in mind that you can just write your PHP and HTML code just mixed like this. Otherwise, please explain more what you are trying to do and consider posting more detailed code as it's not very clear to me.

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div id="div1"><?php echo 'some message'; ?></div>
      <input type="submit" id="submit1">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also use `<?= 'some message' ?>` which is equivalent to `<?php echo 'some message' =>`.